# Django how to handle two forms with one-to-many relationship between models in one post

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

For the sake of simplicity, here is a short version of the issue I am dealing with. Say you have two models, Product and ProductPricing, with Product having many ProductPricing instances and a product pricing is related to only one product (one-to-many relationship). The model's clean method:

models.py:

```
class ProductPricing(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name = 'prices', verbose_name = 'Price', blank = True, null = True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name = 'customer_pricings', blank = True, null = True)
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if not self.product and not self.customer:
            raise ValidationError(_('Pricing requires either a product or a customer. None is provided') )
```

forms.py:

```
class ProductPricingAddonForm(ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = ProductPricing
        fields = ['UOM', 'cost_per_UOM', 'product']
```

Now, In my UpdateView, I am doing something like this:

```
class UpdateProductView(View):
    template_name = 'product.html'
    product_form = ProductForm
    pricing_form = ProductPricingAddonForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_id = kwargs.get('pk', None)
        product = Product.objects.get(id = product_id)

        product_form = self.product_form()
        pricing_form = self.pricing_form()

        c = {}
        c['product_form'] = product_form
        c['pricing_form'] = pricing_form

        return render(request, self.template_name, c)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' To update both the models in one go'''

        product_id = kwargs.get('pk', None)
        product = Product.objects.get(id = product_id)
        product_pricing = ProductPricing.objects.filter(product = product)

        product_form = self.product_form(request.POST if any(request.POST) else None, request.FILES or None, instance = product)
        if product_form.is_valid():
            product_form.save()
            product_form_validity_flag = True
            updated_product = Product.objects.get(id = product_id)
        else:
            product_form_errors = product_form.errors
        ...
        # if no existing pricing specified for the product:
        pricing_form = self.pricing_form(request.POST if any(request.POST) else None, request.FILES or None)    
        # Since a productpricing instance is required to have product or customer, the updated_product should somehow be attached to the form:
        pricing_form['product'] = updated_product     # <-- Error here
        if pricing_form.is_valid():
            pricing_form.save()
            pricing_form_validity_flag
        else:
            pricing_form_errors = pricing_form.errors

        if product_form_validity_flag and pricing_form_validity_flag:
            return reverse(...)
        else:
            c = {'product_form': product_form,
                  'pricing_form': pricing_form }
            return render(request, self.template_name, c)
```

The problem is when submitting the form, I get the error message that 'ProductPricingAddonForm' object does not support item assignment. Note, if I do not provide the product to the productpricing form somehow, the validation error defined in the clean method of the ProductPricing model will be thrown at me.

So, my question is how to attach the parent instance (product) to the child instance (productpricing) in the same post method (i.e. not creating a productpricing in a different page)?

Comment: Typically, once a form has been bound, it's fields can not be edited. You need to create another instance.
Refer to this : [bound and unbound forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms).

Comment: @coderDude, I will like you are onto something there. I did try to copy the post data, create a dictionary, and add the foreign keys to generate a full set of data for my modelform.  Then, I passed that to the my modelform to create a bound form.  However, I got another error message on the product field of my ProductPricingAddonForm: ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'].  I found a way around the problem though.  I created a form (and not a modelform), took the post data, added foreignkey data for product, and voila! The form submitted with no errors!